# CountIf Excel VBA Identify Where Range Condition Met VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to use CountIf to return a Range within VBA?

> Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(MyRange, x) > 1

I would like to take the Range where CountIf finds X in MyRange, and manipulate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't really return a Range in a function unless it's an UDF

Comment: I have a working macro already using .Find.  I was looking into speeding it up a bit using CountIF.  I have yet to explore User Defined Functions, but see plenty of them in my future.

Comment: Couldn't you just filter for "X" and then work on visible cells?

Comment: I could, but with over 100,000 rows of unique data, it is not efficient.  I do not want to make changes to the original data as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does appear Find may be faster than CountIF.  I made an example of each below using a fair amount of data.  With this finding, along with not being able to manipulate my second range in count if, is good enough for me to continue to use Find in the code.  Also, CountIF is not case sensitive!  Thanks everyone for your input.

```
Sub Test()
Dim i As Integer
Dim Range1 As Range
'Range1 values will always have a match in Range2
Dim Range2 As Range
'Range2 values will only appear once and are never duplicated
Dim t As Long

t = Timer
Set Range1 = Range("A1:A100")
Set Range2 = Range("B1:B100000")

For i = 1 To 30000
    Cells(i, 1).Value = i
    Cells(i, 2).Value = i
Next i
'i overflow error after 30000 or so

'This is the only part of code that changed
'First 100 cells of Column A and B turn red
For Each x In Range1
    Set y = Range2.Find(What:=x, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not y Is Nothing Then
    y.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    x.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
Next x

MsgBox ("done " & Timer)
'find method time = ~56166
'countif method = ~56232

End Sub
```

Versus

```
Sub Test()

Dim i As Integer
Dim Range1 As Range
'Range1 values will always have a match in Range2
Dim Range2 As Range
'Range2 values will only appear once and are never duplicated
Dim t As Long

t = Timer
Set Range1 = Range("A1:A100")
Set Range2 = Range("B1:B100000")

For i = 1 To 30000
    Cells(i, 1).Value = i
    Cells(i, 2).Value = i
Next i
'i overflow error after 30000 or so

'This is the only part of code that changed
'First 100 cells of Column A turn red
For Each x In Range1
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range2, x) > 0 Then
    'dunno where Range2 match is - cannot manipulate
    x.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
Next x

MsgBox ("done " & Timer)
'find method time = ~56166
'countif method = ~56232

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

**Find** is pretty fast:

```
Sub FindX()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Cells.Find(What:="X", After:=Range("A1"))
    If Not r is nothing Then MsgBox r.Address(0, 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: While Find is fast, in my current macro it is the longest step.  I am finding each x in a range of a few hundred cells, inside of each x of a range containing 100,000 plus cells.  If it is not possible using CountIf, I will research UDF next.  Thanks

Comment: + 1 Made a little change though. @user2662041: `.Find` is fast enough. And definitely faster than `CountIf` over a huge range. Can you give an exact example of what are you trying to achieve?